# Is there any question about the route code in my flutter code?

Tags: flutter, routes

I want to make a new route in the flutter , but I failed, 
my VS Code give me this:

> **The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
>   I/flutter (32582): Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
>   I/flutter (32582): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a
>   I/flutter (32582): descendant of a Navigator widget**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()=>runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Lake',
      routes: {
        'sss': (context)=>new NewRoute()
      },
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Lake'),
        ),
        body: Text('BBB'),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.import_contacts),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'sss');
          },
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}

class NewRoute extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BBB'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('wahaha'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Builder` like this:

```
home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Lake'),
        ),
        body: Text('BBB'),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.import_contacts),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'sss');
          },
        ),
      ),)
```

`Builder` lets you build a new context from direct parent as described here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using routes incorrectly. when you  use home in MaterialApp it will bypass the Routes. insted of that you can use initialRoute to define Home Screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Lake',
      routes: {
        'sss': (context) => const NewRoute(),
        'home': (context) => const HomeScreen(),
      },
      initialRoute: 'home',
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Lake'),
      ),
      body: const Text('BBB'),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.import_contacts),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'sss');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BBB'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('wahaha'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

also avoid using new keyword.
you can also try with onGenarated Routes in flutter.
[more information](https://flutteragency.com/ongenerateroute-and-routes-in-flutter/)